# Subgroups of $PSL_2(\mathbb Z/m\mathbb Z)$

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ and $H$ be two (finite) groups. Say that $G$ is "involved" in $H$ if $G$ is a quotient of a subgroup of $H$.

The question is the following : prove that, for every $m$, there is a prime $p$ and $r\geq 1$ such that any group involved in $PSL_2(\mathbb Z/m\mathbb Z)$ is involved in $PSL_2(\mathbb Z/p^r\mathbb Z)$.

Of course, it is enough to do it only for $PSL_2(\mathbb Z/m\mathbb Z)$ itself. It's tempting to use the Chinese Remainder Theorem : this group is a product of groups of the form $PSL_2(\mathbb Z/p_i^{r_i}\mathbb Z)$. And then I'm blocked... Am I missing something ?

Comment: Just a comment before I think about the question: $G$ is usually called a "section" of $H$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the question is not correctly worded.  As it is currently worded, it is impossible.

Take *m* = 77, then as you say PSL(2,**Z**/77**Z**) ≅ PSL(2,7) × PSL(2,11).  However, the non-abelian simple groups involved in PSL(2,**Z**/*p*<sup>*r*</sup>**Z**) are at most PSL(2,*p*) and PSL(2,5).  In particular,  PSL(2,7) × PSL(2,11) is never involved in PSL(2,**Z**/*p*<sup>*r*</sup>**Z**).

Comment: How exactly do you know that the only simple non-abelian groups involved in PSL(2,$\mathbf Z/p^r\mathbf Z$) are PSL(2,p) and PSL(2,5)?

Comment: PSL(2,Z/p^rZ) has a normal p-subgroup with quotient PSL(2,p), so any simple section of PSL(2,Z/p^rZ) is already a simple section of PSL(2,p).  The subgroups of PSL(2,p) are dihedral, subgroups of AGL(1,p), or the "platonic" subgroups A4, A5, S4.  The only one with a simple section is A5.

Comment: Wow, thanks. That was slightly more nontrivial than I expected.

Comment: Thanks ! The question is taken from an exercise in a book in group theory. I guess I shouldn't always trust books...